# Tell Mercurial not to deploy a particular directory when updating

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible to tell Mercurial to not deploy a particular directory when updating to a particular branch? I have a repository and on the "prod" branch I have some unit tests in a particular directory that I need there so that when testing on the CI server the tests are run against the "prod" code base, however I don't want them deployed to the production server.

Is it possible, in a hook or something similar to tell Mercurial to exclude this particular directory from the deployment when pushing the code to the production server?

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this for a while and talking over with a college the solution seemed quite obvious, simply add a changegroup hook to delete the directories, so in addition to the update and gulp tasks already be run on update I added a delete command to remove the directory:

```
changegroup = hg up -C prod & gulp && /bin/rm -Rf [directoryToDelete]
```